# how to select keypath for keyframe animation in Scenekit?

Tags: scenekit

am trying to animate targetPosition in SCNIKConstraint using CAKeyFrame but cant figure out what keypath to use when setting up the animation.

Two questions:

1. Can targetPosition be animated using keyFrame?
2. in general where/how cn i locate the keypath for SceneKit animatable properties

Answer (score 0):

Any property of a type that conforms to `SCNAnimatable` can be animated. This is the case here as `SCNIKConstraint` inherit from `SCNConstraint` which conforms to it.

Then you can animate properties by specifying their path.

In your case you'll do something like this:

```
let constraint = SCNIKConstraint(...)
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "targetPosition")
/// Configure the animation
...
constraint.addAnimation(animation, forKey:nil)
```

Be careful to set values for the animation that are compatible with the property you want to animate.

Note: You can specify properties or derived properties with their paths, the smae way you can access them through the [`value(forKeyPath: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416468-value) method of `NSObject`. For example, you could do this:

```
 let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "targetPosition.x")
```

Comment: Thx much for your response